# Check if property exists

Tags: php, getter-setter

Is it possible to check if a property exists which are set using magic setter?

```
class Test
{
    private $vars;

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function &__get($key)
    {
        return $this->vars[$key];
    }
}

$test = new Test;

$test->myvar = 'yay!';

if (magic_isset($test->myvar)) {
}
```

Or isn't it possible and I just need to setup another function in my class?

Comment: try looking at __isset http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: No really as @danjordan says try looking at property_exists in php5+ http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

Comment: My guess is people are most likely looking for [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) landing here from a search engine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`__isset()`](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) and [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset):

```
public function __isset($key)
{
    return isset($this->vars[$key]);
}
```

```
$test = new Test;

$test->myvar = 'yay!';

if (isset($test->myvar)) {

}
```

Comment: `isset`'s behaviour is not the same as `property_exist` function (ie, if a property exists but equals `null` or `false`, `isset` returns normally `false`). This solution (but also the question) is quite ambiguous.