# How to dynamically assign values from associative array to properties

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I'm trying to assign keys and values from an associative array to class properties..the code below is what I have come up with. I get error when I try to use $user object. Array may come from running database query(PDO).

Is there a way I can make this work?

```
<?php

class assoctoprop {

public $fname;
public $lname;
public $email;

public function assign(){
    $user = new assoctoprop;
    $array = array("fname"=>"firstname", "lname"=>"lastname", "email"=>"my@email.com" );
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $user->$key = $value;
    }
    return $user;
}
}
echo $user->fname."<br/>";
echo $user->lname."<br/>";
echo $user->email."<br/>";
?>
```

This works

```
<?php

class assoctoprop {

public $fname;
public $lname;
public $email;

/*public function assign(){
    $user = new assoctoprop;
    $array = array("fname"=>"firstname", "lname"=>"lastname", "email"=>"my@email.com" );
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $user->$key = $value;
    }
    return $user;
}*/
}
          $user = new assoctoprop;
    $array = array("fname"=>"firstname", "lname"=>"lastname", "email"=>"my@email.com" );
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $user->$key = $value;
    }
echo $user->fname;
echo $user->lname;
echo $user->email;
?>
```

But the problem I have with this is that, I want to push the whole process into a method, so that I can use it when I want and not necessarily write the procedure all over again each time

Comment: Yes. Can I instantiate the class from within the assign method ?

Comment: If your using PDO then you can return the result as a user defined object. You can use the setFetchMode() method of the PDOStatement object to return an object. http://www.snippetbank.net/2014/05/php-introduction-to-pdo-part-2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `assign()` looks to me like it should be outside the class at this point.

You can instantiate a class from within itself, but in this case you don't need to. Just use `$this` to refer to the class from within:

```
class assoctoprop {

    public $fname;
    public $lname;
    public $email;

    public function assign(){
        $array = array("fname"=>"firstname", "lname"=>"lastname", "email"=>"my@email.com" );
        foreach($array as $key=>$value){
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }

}

$user = new assoctoprop;
$user->assign();

echo $user->fname."<br/>";
echo $user->lname."<br/>";
echo $user->email."<br/>";
```

You should also consider passing that array into the function instead of defining it inside the class, and you should do some basic error checking to make sure the property exists before you set it, etc.

**Edit:** you could also make your `assign()` method into the [class's constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), so it would be called immediately:

```
class assoctoprop {
    public $fname;
    public $lname;
    public $email;

    function __construct($array){
        foreach($array as $key=>$value){
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }    
}

$array = array("fname"=>"firstname", "lname"=>"lastname", "email"=>"my@email.com" );
$user = new assoctoprop($array);

echo $user->fname."<br/>";
echo $user->lname."<br/>";
echo $user->email."<br/>";
```

**Edit 2:** [here's an interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729830/check-if-a-property-exists-on-magically-set-properties) about using class properties that may not exist yet (in case you wanted to make this dynamic).

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you could accomplish this same thing by just setting the type on the array to object.

```
$object = (object)array("fname" => "firstname", "lname" => "lastname", "email" => "my@email.com");
```