# isset behaving strangely when used with objects

Tags: php, isset

I have code similar to the following. I get the template from the db and assign it to the framework object. Strangely now, when checking if the template variable is set isset always returns false. The

```
echo $framework->getSys()->template;
```

even prints the content of the variable. How can this behaviour be explained and, more important, how can i solve the problem of always assigning the default template?

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) { // isset works like expected
    $result = $framework->getSys()->db->query("SELECT t.name FROM users AS u, templates AS t WHERE u.id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND u.template = t.id LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($framework->getSys()->db));
    if ($result) {
        while($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $framework->getSys()->template = $obj->name;
        }
    }
}

if (!isset($framework->getSys()->template)) {
    echo $framework->getSys()->template; // This prints the template from the db
    $framework->getSys()->template = "default";
}
```

Comment: What's the actual value of `$framework->getSys()->template` before the `if` statement? Do a `var_dump` or something

Comment: Perhaps you should be using `empty()`

Comment: If there is no template specified in the db the variable isn't set. In case it is its a string like "dark_blue" for example.

@ginovva320: But isn't isset designed for this very reason - to check if a variable is set? empty would result in a php notification to access a not existend variable.

Comment: `isset` typically works only with *variables*. `$framework->getSys()->template` is a pretty complex expression including a function call, not a simple variable or property. I'm not sure how it *should* react and I think it also varies by PHP version, but this doesn't seem like a case where `isset` is appropriate to begin with. Why are you using it here in the first place? What exactly may *not* be set?

Comment: The element to check is the `template` attribute of the result from `getSys()`, which is basically a "registry" with magic setters and getters.

Comment: I just found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763357/check-if-property-exists).